# App connected to mobile data can still access local network

Tags: networking, internet-connection, ip-camera

This has been freaking me out recently.

It's a house that has two security cameras (TP-Link Tapo), and they are connected through Wifi to the Wifi router installed in the attic. Their local network IPs are like 192.168.x.x.

I can watch them on my Pixel phone using the Tapo camera app. I don't have any subscription, not paying or anything like that.

So as long the phone is connected to the same Wifi router, I should be able to see them and I do.

But the weird thing is that if I disable Wifi on the phone, and use mobile data, I can still watch the cameras! The IP assigned by the mobile carrier is different than the IP assigned by the ISP to the Wifi router.

How is this possible? The only explanation that comes in my mind is that the phone is somehow secretly connecting to the Wifi too, but this would be like huge privacy breach (from Google) because it's connecting without your consent.

Comment: That's not the only explanation. The app may have access over internet enabled. Please check the user's manual and other documentation before making assumptions.

Comment: what does "access over internet enabled" mean?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Many cameras allow access over local network -and- internet. A subscription service is often required but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Access over the internet is a standard feature with (most) devices from the Tapo series so this behavior is by design when using the app (I think the cloud account is used for the connection it's just that you have limited/no cloud storage if you are not on a payment plan). You can verify this by blocking internet access to your router which your cams are connected to. Once this is the case you won't be able to access them any more via your mobil phone when it's not connected to your WLAN any more.

Depending on your model there are several ways and/or workarounds to block the interent access e.g. [this one for the TPLink Tapo C200](https://www.reddit.com/r/TpLink/comments/nsxxwx/tplink_tapo_c200_disable_internet_streaming_but/). Just look for a guide by searching for `tapo block internet connection` and add your model.

Give it a try and expand on your question if you run into problems (or start a new question).

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the situation completely but it sounds like someone ( the owner of the Tapo device) shared the Tapo account with you for you to see the recording.
And yes you should be able to check the recording while wifi is off and mobile data is on ( a feature that allows ppl to check the recording while away from the wifi network). However, if the Tapo app on your cell phone does not have access to mobile data then you will not be able to check the camera or recording without wifi.

I apologize if this response does not address the issue you encountered.

Comment: Is this from chatgpt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).